# why is that I can't create an instance_free feature in a deferred class?

Tags: eiffel

I'd like to create a class with both an instance_free (`ensure class`) feature and a `deferred` one.

why is that I can't **call** an instance_free feature in a deferred class but only on a descendant?

Don't understand the logic of that... is there for compiling reasons? or any sense I don't see? Where am I wrong with my logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an implementation constraint of the current version of EiffelStudio (19.07). It is going to be removed in the future.